# Classic ASP: log database errors

Tags: logging, asp-classic

I implemented a simple function to create a log of my Classic ASP web application.
I can see all messages I set in the code (with a string like `WriteLog("my message")`, but I need to write in log errors coming from database (I'm using `ADODB.Connection` to connect to several databases, fro example Oracle, AS400, SQL Srv, etc...).

How can I catch a db error and write it on log file?

Comment: Here's a post about error handling in vbscript; 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/handling-errors-in-vbscript

Answer (score 0):

you would call your function any time you do anything with the database, whether it's simply connecting to it, running a query against it, or whatever:

```
conn.open connString
if Err.Number <> 0 then WriteLog("error connection")

set rs = conn.Execute("<sql query>")
if Err.Number <> 0 then WriteLog("error running query")
```

if this doesnt answer your question, please be more specific on what you want to accomplish